# Cells of JTable in JTree issue, cells are not selectable, select event of cells is not fired

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

I'm struggling with rendering a JTable as a node of a JTree. Displaying the table works fine with extending DefaultTreeCellRenderer and DefaultTableCellRenderer but selecting the cells of the rendered JTable doesn't work anymore.

Are there more things that have to be implemented, or are there more options to set? The TableCellRenderer should not cause the issue because rendering outside the JTree, the cells of the JTable are selectable.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we also can reproduce your problem. Simply create a class with the main method, `JTree` and your renderer, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The renderer of a JTree uses the underlying component to draw the component; the component itself is not traditional in the sense that it doesn't gain focus when a node in the tree is selected. You can see this in the [`JTree.getTreeCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html#getTreeCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTree,java.lang.Object,boolean,boolean,boolean,int,boolean)) documentation: `[...]Returns the Component that the renderer uses to draw the value.[...]`.

Comment: I have never done this myself, but I think you want to edit the node when selected to achieve what you want. Install a proper [TreeCellEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellEditor.html), that should receive traditional events.